# FFMPEG объединение RTP потоков в один

Tags: python, ffmpeg, sip, rtp

Всем добрый день! Появилась проблема, застряли в разработке. Пишем свой SIP сервер B2BUA, дошли до момента создания комнат для объединения большого количества абонентов. Появилась необходимость использования FFMPEG, в котором ну вообще не сильны. Документацию изучаем, но не можем найти пояснения как объединить несколько RTP потоков в один. Если кто сталкивался с такой проблемой и нашел в документации то, что необходимо, мы были бы очень признательны!

Comment: А какого конкретно результата вы хотите добиться? Как должен выглядеть этот один поток?

Comment: Но внутренний телепат подсказывает мне что-то такое https://stackoverflow.com/a/33764934

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.